# Proof of Health Insurance to enter Ukraine?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, ukraine

Is proof of Health Insurance checked on a 3-day visit? If so, would a Heath Insurance ID card be needed for this, or would the Travel Accident Insurance provided through some Visa cards be sufficient? (its not quite my definition of health insurance, but it covers some health related trauma)

[U.S. Passports & International Travel](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/ukraine.html)

> You do not need a visa to enter Ukraine for visits of up to 90 days in any 180 day period, but **must be able to provide proof of valid health insurance** and sufficient funds for the duration of your stay.

Comment: As of now health insurance is [requested](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/118-2017-%D0%BF)  when you apply for a visa. However, it is [not a requirement](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/3773-17/page2) to enter the country. One needs a passport and solvency proof, just this. I never heard of border check for health insurance (actually, solvency is rarely, if ever, checked too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, such proof is never requested by Ukrainian border guards.

Source: traveling to Ukraine 5+ times in the last couple of years. In addition [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=NL&DE=UA&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX) fails to mention any such requirements.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was a bit of an odd thing to have listed - hadn't seen that one before